# How to trace the raw HTTP Request invoked using WebClient?

Tags: c#, webclient, system.diagnostics

What is the best method to trace programmatically the full raw HTTP request when using the WebClient class?

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve it programmactically by using System.Net tracing

See example here on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824.aspx

Comment: Thanks. This works but what I'm really after is a method that would give me access to the data within the code itself.